# Keras Error: Please provide data which shares the same first dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I try to use a customize layer in keras. It's a simple layer just a matmul with trainable params.

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.layers import Layer
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

class MultiLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(MultiLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer
        if self.output_dim[0] != input_shape[1]:
            raise Exception("expect input shape with [{},?], but get input with shape {}".format(self.output_dim[0],input_shape), input_shape)
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                      shape=(input_shape[2], self.output_dim[0]),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(MultiLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end
    def call(self, x):
        return K.dot(x, self.kernel)
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)

x_fake = np.random.random((10,28,28))
y_fake = [np.diag(np.ones(28))]*10
input_shape = np.shape(x_fake)[1:]
print(input_shape)
ipt = Input(name='inputs',shape=input_shape)
layer = MultiLayer((input_shape[0],input_shape[0]),name="dev")(ipt)
#layer = Flatten()(layer)
model = Model(inputs=ipt,outputs=layer)
model.summary()
rms = RMSprop()
model.compile(loss="rms", optimizer=rms, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_fake,y_fake)
```

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
inputs (InputLayer)          [(None, 28, 28)]          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dev (MultiLayer)             (None, 28, 28)            784       
=================================================================
Total params: 784
Trainable params: 784
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

but when I fit this model, error occurs.

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 10
  y sizes: 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28

Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

I don't know what the sizes mean.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model.output_shape` must match `y_fake.shape`; your `[np.diag(np.ones((28,28)))]*10` is a list of 10 arrays, each of shape `(28, 28)`, so TF thinks you have 10 outputs. I presume you intended `np.stack(... * 10)`.

Next, ensure all imports are consistent (either `from tensorflow.keras` or `from keras`). Lastly, "rms" isn't a supported loss, I replaced it with `"mse"`.  All fixes below.

---

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

class MultiLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(MultiLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer
        if self.output_dim[0] != input_shape[1]:
            raise Exception(("expect input shape with [{},?], but get input with "
                             "shape {}").format(self.output_dim[0],input_shape),
                            input_shape)
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                                      shape=(input_shape[2], self.output_dim[0]),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(MultiLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):
        return K.dot(x, self.kernel)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)

x_fake = np.random.random((10,28,28))
y_fake = np.stack([np.diag(np.ones((28)))]*10)  # (10, 28, 28)
input_shape = np.shape(x_fake)[1:]
print(input_shape)

ipt = Input(name='inputs', shape=input_shape)
layer = MultiLayer((input_shape[0],input_shape[0]),name="dev")(ipt)
model = Model(inputs=ipt, outputs=layer)

model.summary()
rms = RMSprop()
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=rms, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_fake, y_fake)
```

Comment: it should be “y_fake = [np.diag(np.ones(28))]*10", and the shape is (10, 28, 28)